# Select From List of Nested Associations

Tags: dataset, filtering, associations

I have an association:

```
association = {<|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> "test", 
 "gameLength" -> "regulation"|>, "away" -> <|"Hits" -> 33, 
 "golieData" -> {<|"number" -> 30, 
    "link" -> "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470147", 
    "No." -> 30, "Player" -> "C. McElhinney", "EV" -> {32, 33}, 
    "PP" -> {2, 2}, "SH" -> {0, 0}, "Saves - Shots" -> {34, 35}, 
    "Sv%" -> 0.971, "PIM" -> 0, "TOI" -> "60:00"|>}
 |>, "home" -> <|"Hits" -> 24., 
 "golieData" -> {<|"number" -> 40, 
    "link" -> "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8471695", 
    "No." -> 40, "Player" -> "T. Rask", "EV" -> {21, 22}, 
    "PP" -> {7, 8}, "SH" -> {0, 0}, "Saves - Shots" -> {28, 30}, 
    "Sv%" -> 0.933, "PIM" -> 0, 
    "TOI" -> "59:26"|>, <|"number" -> 45, 
    "link" -> "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169", 
    "No." -> 40, "Player" -> "T. Rask", "EV" -> {21, 22}, 
    "PP" -> {7, 8}, "SH" -> {0, 0}, "Saves - Shots" -> {28, 30}, 
    "Sv%" -> 0.933, "PIM" -> 0, "TOI" -> "59:26"|>}
 |> |>,  <|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> "blah", "gameLength" -> "playoff"|>, "away" -> <|"Hits" -> 12, 
 "golieData" -> {<|"number" -> 30, 
    "link" -> "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8468524", 
    "No." -> 30, "Player" -> "I. Bryzgalov", "EV" -> {17, 17}, 
    "PP" -> {5, 6}, "SH" -> {0, 0}, "Saves - Shots" -> {22, 23}, 
    "Sv%" -> 0.957, "PIM" -> 0, "TOI" -> "60:00"|>}
 |>, "home" -> <|"Hits" -> 4, 
 "golieData" -> {<|"number" -> 30, 
    "link" -> "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8460703", 
    "No." -> 30, "Player" -> "T. Thomas", "EV" -> {22, 23}, 
    "PP" -> {2, 3}, "SH" -> {3, 3}, "Saves - Shots" -> {27, 29}, 
    "Sv%" -> 0.931, "PIM" -> 0, "TOI" -> "59:15"|>}|>|>}
```

and I would like to select the match where the player link is equal to "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169".

I have tried:

```
Query[Select[#[["home", "golieData", All,"link"]] == "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169" &]]@association

Query[Select[#[["home", "golieData", 2, "link"]] == "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169" &]]@association
```

When I try to select by the first player link, it works. I can not seem to access the second players link.

This works for the first player link:

```
Query[Select[#[["home", "golieData", 1, "link"]] == "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8471695" &]]@association
```

but only when the link I am looking for is in the first position.

Is there a better way to structure this data to make this query possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following query will retrieve all matches with a given goalie link:

```
link = "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169";

association // Query[Select[Query["home", "golieData", MemberQ[link], "link"]]]
```

If only the first such match is desired, change `Select` to `SelectFirst`.

**How It Works**

To see how this works, let's build it up piece-by-piece.

We can retrieve a list of links for each match like this:

```
association // Query[All, "home", "golieData", All, "link"]

(* { {"http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8471695",
      "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8470169" }, 
     {"http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8460703"} } *)
```

We can test each of those lists to see whether they contain the desired link by changing the rightmost `All` to `MemberQ[link]`:

```
association // Query[All, "home", "golieData", MemberQ[link], "link"]
(* {True, False} *)
```

All that remains is to retain only those matches that return `True` for this test.  We change the left-most `All` in the previous query to a `Select` that applies the test by means of a subquery:

```
association // Query[Select[Query["home", "golieData", MemberQ[link], "link"]]]

(* {<| basicData -> <|...|>
     , away -> <|Hits->33,golieData->{<|number->30,...|>
     , home-> <|Hits->24.,golieData->{<|number->40,...|>,<|number->45,...|>}|>
     |>} *)
```

`MemberQ` is a so-called "ascending operator".  Queries are processed in two phases: a "descending" phase that primarily applies filters on a top-down basis, and an "ascending" phase that generally performs aggregations on a bottom-up basis.  The sequence of events in the subquery is as follows:

*Descending Phase*

1. From the list of matches, `"home"` selects only the home matches.
2. From each match, `"golieData"` selects only the list of goalies.
3. `MemberQ` is ignored in the descending stage since it is an ascending operator.  No filter is applied to each goalie list (i.e. it is as if this operator were `All` for descending purposes).
4. From each goalie, `"link"` selects only the link value.

*Ascending Phase*

5. `"link"` is ignored in the ascending stage since it is a descending operator.  No function is applied to each link (i.e. it is as if this operator were `Identity` for ascending purposes).
6. `MemberQ`, being an ascending operator, is applied to each list of links thereby converting it into a boolean.
7. The descending operator `"golieData"` is treated as `Identity`, leaving the boolean unchanged.
8. The descending operator `"home"` treated as `Identity`, once again leaving the boolean unchanged.

Thus, each subquery returns a boolean.  The `Select` operator uses this boolean to filter the list of matches.

**Re-using Queries**

It is often helpful to re-use queries such as this.  A helper function makes this possible:

```
goalie[where:"home"|"away", id_String] :=
  Query[where, "golieData", MemberQ["http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id="~~id], "link"]
```

The function is used like this:

```
association // Query[SelectFirst[goalie["away", "8468524"]]]

(* <| basicData -> <|...|>
    , away -> <|Hits->12,golieData->{<|number->30,...|>}|>
    , home -> <|Hits->4,golieData->{<|number->30,...}|>
    |> *)
```

Comment: This is a great solution.

Comment: Didn't even think to use MemberQ.  I'm not clear on why the MemberQ needs to be put at that position in the key.  I would think it needed to be at a different place.  Also, is there another way to apply this to the association other than using the //?  I also thought of another way `Extract[AllMatches, 
 Partition[
  Position[parsedMatches, 
    "http://www.nhl.com/ice/player.htm?id=8471695", Infinity][[All, 
    1]], 1]]`

Comment: "That position" for `MemberQ` is the level that represents the list of links.  `MemberQ` converts the each list into a boolean.  I used `//` purely out of personal preference.  You can write `Query[...] @ association` as in the question if you prefer.

Comment: I expanded the **How It Works** section to discuss the details of how `MemberQ` affects the query.

Comment: @WReach, great solution, however, when the value set (eg `"home" | "away"`) grows, are you forced to manually list `Alternatives`?

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, one would be.  But I added it for its explanatory value in this discussion, not to enforce a restriction (and the same for `_String` in the second argument).  We could just as well have `where_String`, or simply `where_` if that is preferable.  The core solution is insensitive to that choice.